# Convert this to Eloquent from Query Builder, joining and multiple whereor

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use a search page for the record. The below is my Query Builder, I think I have a problem for the performance for query this. I am thinking to switch it to Eloquent and able to use the `toArray()` function to convert it.

```
$records = DB::table('customers')
    ->join('orders', function($join) use ($keyword)
    {
        $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'orders.cust_id')
            //customers
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('address_street', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('address_street2', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('address_city', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('address_postcode', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('contact_mobile', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('contact_email', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('remark', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            //orders
            ->orWhere('order_no', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('delivery_man', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    })
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

I also notice the query is taking long time compare I wrote the sql statement from the query client. The result from this query was taken 4s, the sql query only took 0.3s. Below is the sql statement.

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` 
INNER JOIN `orders` on `customers`.`id` = `orders`.`cust_id` 
WHERE `name` LIKE '%keyword%' or `address_street` LIKE '%keyword%' 
    or `address_street2` LIKE '%keyword%' or `address_city` LIKE '%keyword%' 
    or `address_postcode` LIKE '%keyword%' or `contact_mobile` LIKE '%keyword%' 
    or `contact_office` LIKE '%keyword%' or `contact_email` LIKE '%keyword%' 
    or `remark` LIKE '%keyword%' or `order_no` LIKE '%keyword%' 
    or `delivery_man` LIKE '%keyword%' 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: i don't think the problem is the query builder here. it is just a simple sql statement. the difference can not be more than 12 times. and moreover the query seems to be little bit illogical on the 1st glance. e.g. how can be a email and postcode can contain the same format???? the proper approach should be, in the search form, give inputs for each field and then search according to it.

Comment: I am having a search box to search all of the fields. It does not matter what is the format. I have the table to fill the information.

Comment: run with `DB::select()` and see how much time it takes.

Comment: if running with DB:select() it means run with normal sql statement, the output is same like I run in sql client. My goal is convert it to Eloquent with the same query.